# mySQL query and save results to new table

Tags: php, mysql

I am importing some info from a web API call into a MySQL table I have the import working but am new to SQL queries.

My table is called ticks and my columns are `id`, `price`, `qnty`, `timestamp`.

```
Table Structure:

Column    Type  
id        int(11)                
price     decimal(9,8)               
quantity  int(15)            
timestamp bigint(15)
```

Sample data:

```
+-------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
|   id  |       price      |  quantity   |    timestamp     |
+-------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
|   1   |    0.00015350    |    22       |   1514903400076  |
+-------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
|   2   |    0.00015350    |    94       |   1514903401160  |
+-------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
|   3   |    0.00015344    |    20       |   1514903402972  |
+-------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
|   4   |    0.00015340    |    423      |   1514903402972  |
+-------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
|   5   |    0.00015361    |    98       |   1514903403026  |
+-------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
|   6   |    0.00015361    |    64       |   1514903403282  |
+-------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
|   7   |    0.00015360    |    10       |   1514903404542  |
+-------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
|   8   |    0.00015361    |    87       |   1514903404635  |
+-------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

I want to find all records that are <= a timestamp then
find all the price duplicates and add up the qnty.

In the end I want to find total qnty at each unique price for the 30min period.

I need to do this for 13 time periods. The entire table which is about 87000 records.

so far I have the following..which works.

```
SELECT * FROM `ticks` WHERE timestamp <= '1514905199000' ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Can I do all of it in one query?

I figure I have to store the results into a new table?

Kind Regards,

Mike

Comment: please add your table structrue with some data and also add your expected result

Comment: Incidentally, the number in parentheses following the int or bigint keyword is (almost) completely meaningless

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query